# Как удалить узел в дереве?

Tags: бинарное-дерево, c++

Понимаю, что вопрос дурацкий, но все же: нужно удалить узел дерева, при этом чтобы у "родителя" узла обнулить указатель на узел. У узла гарантированно нет потомков.

```
//cur — текущий элемент, par — ссылка на его родителя
if (cur->par->left == cur) cur->par->left = 0;
if (cur->par->right == cur) cur->par->right = 0;
delete cur;
```

Этот код не работает, выдает ошибку во время выполнения.
Очень прошу помочь.

Собственно структура узла дерева:

```
struct Node
{
    char data;
    int weight;
    bool symbol;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* par;
};
```

УПД:
Спасибо всем за помощь, ошибка самая банальная: во время создания дерева при создании нового узла забыл делать указатель на родителя. Извините за потраченное время.

Comment: Какую ошибку? В какой строке? Какой из указателей, которые разыменовываются в коде, нулевой? Как описана структура, представляющая собой узел дерева?

Телепатов у нас не так много, простите великодушно.

Comment: Меня простите, я слегка косноязычен. Ни один из указателей не нулевой. Насчет "в какой строке" — ошибку выдает во время выполнения, а не компиляции, т. е. все действия до этого выполняются, ошибка происходит во время сравнения if (cur->par->left == cur). По поводу "имеют право быть нулевыми" не понял, извиняйте.
Обновил вопрос, там описывается структура.

Comment: @bambimbom: А как насчёт `cur->par`? Он случайно не нулевой?

«Имеют право» означает вот что. Вы как архитектор кода для каждого указателя можете либо запланировать, что он никогда не может быть нулевым (тогда его можно не проверять на NULL при разыменовании, но надо проверять при записи), либо может (тогда писать в него можно что угодно, но при разыменовании надо проверять).

Вот например, поле `par` имеет право быть нулевым указателем?

Comment: А как это узнать, имеет или не имеет?

Comment: @bambimbom: Вы же архитектор кода, откуда нам знать, какое вы приняли решение? Как вы решили, когда писали код, так и правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, непонятно, вам надо удалить всё поддерево(то есть удалить и потомков удаляемой ячейки) или удалить саму ячейку а её потомков "привязать" к родителю?

Во вторых непонятна сама структура дерева, построена она в стиле С или С++ (ооп).

В третьих читаем комментарий от VladD

Но алгоритм удаления поддерева прост:

1. делаем функцию удалить_дерево(ячейка дерева)
2. в ней если у корня есть потомки то
       сначала вызвать
       удалить_дерево(потомок)
3. после того как потомки удалены,
       удаляем саму ячейку